# Input check to custom post type query

Tags: wp-query

I have a series of inputs with the custom post ID as the value.

When I write the query manually with specific ID's it works fine and the right custom posts appear.

However, when I've been trying to write it so the IDs are not and the user can choose, nothing appears despite I know the ID is right.

This is the right query;

```
$args = array( 
'post_type' => 'house_types',
'posts_per_page' => 999,
'orderby' => 'date',
'order'   => 'ASC',
'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'development_plots',
            'value' => '92',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'development_plots',
            'value' => '392',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
)
);
```

And this is my query I've tried to write, which is showing nothing back;

```
$development_plots_query = '';
if(!empty($development_plots_choices)){
    $post_per_page = -1;
    foreach($development_plots_choices as $development_plots_query){
        $development_plots_query[] = array( 
            'key' => 'development_plots', 
            'value' => $development_plots_choices, 
            'compare' => 'LIKE' 
        );
    }
}
```

Which then comes into this;

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'house_types',
    'posts_per_page'=> $post_per_page,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order'   => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',            
        $development_plots_query
    ),
);
```

In terms of printing out the $args, this is the right one;

```
Array ( [post_type] => house_types [posts_per_page] => 999 [orderby] => date [order] => ASC [meta_query] => Array ( [relation] => OR [0] => Array ( [key] => development_plots [value] => 92 [compare] => LIKE ) [1] => Array ( [key] => development_plots [value] => 392 [compare] => LIKE ) ) ) Array ( [post_type] => house_types [posts_per_page] => 999 [orderby] => date [order] => ASC [meta_query] => Array ( [relation] => OR [0] => Array ( [key] => development_plots [value] => 92 [compare] => LIKE ) [1] => Array ( [key] => development_plots [value] => 392 [compare] => LIKE ) ) ) Array ( [post_type] => house_types [posts_per_page] => 999 [orderby] => date [order] => ASC [meta_query] => Array ( [relation] => OR [0] => Array ( [key] => development_plots [value] => 92 [compare] => LIKE ) [1] => Array ( [key] => development_plots [value] => 392 [compare] => LIKE ) ) )
```

Against the "broken" one;

```
Array ( [post_type] => house_types [posts_per_page] => -1 [orderby] => date [order] => ASC [meta_query] => Array ( [relation] => AND [0] => Array ( [0] => [1] => Array ( [key] => 0 [value] => 392 [compare] => IN ) ) [1] => Array ( [0] => [1] => Array ( [key] => 0 [value] => 392 [compare] => IN ) ) [2] => Array ( [0] => [1] => Array ( [key] => 0 [value] => 392 [compare] => IN ) ) [3] => [4] => ) )
```

I can see there is a massive difference, but can't work out where I'm going wrong...

Any pointers in the right direction are helpful and hopefully, I've explained it all ok.

Comment: There are several issues in your code, but what's the value of the meta `development_plots`? Is it a single number or a comma-separated list of numbers? Can you update the question with the output of `var_dump( $development_plots_choices );` ?

Comment: Hi @SallyCJ sorry for the late reply, I've done var_dump and it's come back with `NULL string(2) "92"` which is the ID I want it to query.

Comment: Hi Sam, so how about the meta value? Is it a single number?

Comment: Hi Sally, 

Yeah it is, unless the users select's multiple checkboxes in that section so it would then be 92, 106 etc.

Comment: So I ported my answer to [this gist](https://gist.github.com/5ally/b9ceafc231d5cdc6b51ea858816e0063). And if you need further help with the data structure, try asking on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/). :)